# How can I add imports to an "eval"ed piece of clojure code?

Tags: clojure

I would like to evaluate some clojure code entered by users interactively, and I would like to "use" certain namespaces and "import" certain Java classes as well. I end up running the code using:

```
(defn execute-command [string-command]
    let [
        code-with-context  (add-code-context string-command)
        result             (eval(read-string code-with-context))
        ]

        result
)
```

My question is how can I program "add-code-context" to add the required context to the code in "string-command"?

Comment: ah, that let formatting hurts ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to. Any "use"d or "import"ed namspaces/classes are available to the code you eval e.g.

```
(require '[clojure.set :as set])
(-> "(set/union #{1} #{2})" read-string eval)
; => #{1 2}
```

Comment: Is this the same as "(eval (read-string "(set/union #{1} #{2})") ?

Comment: @Zubair Yes (you just forgot one `)` at the end). Nice tutorial for `->` macro: http://kotka.de/blog/2010/04/Did_you_know_II.html